# Rule fails in snakemake, but script runs fine outside of snakemake

Tags: http, timeout, snakemake

I am testing my snakemake pipeline, and it fails on the final step, where it calls a tool I developed - KEGGCharter. The command for this tool runs fine without snakemake, but it fails with `RuleException: FileNotFoundError`, because a file it creates, and is available throughout the execution of the pipeline, it removed at the end, by snakemake. I see that snakemake does this everytime a rule fails, it removes the expected outputs. However, KEGGCharter runs fine outside of snakemake, with the same command!

KEGGCharter loads KEGG maps using Biopython, and some of those loadings will fail with `connection time out`. This is catch inside KEGGCharter with a try except, but does snakemake see this errors and considers an exit code != 0? I have also tried putting the `exit(0)` at the end of the KEGGCharter script, but the result is the same.

Comment: Probably because snakemake uses [bash strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/).

Comment: Try running snakemake with the `--printshellcmds` flag to see the exact commands that it runs. Then check the actual error codes from your program.

Comment: try the --debug-dag I had a similar error where it was just a typo that snakemake failed to point out.